# Model and migration for a Rails app that allows users to follow/subscribe to posts with certain tags (like in SO)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a *Tag*, *User* and *Post* model:

**tag.rb:**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy  
  has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
end
```

tagging.rb:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post  
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

(There is a many-to-many association between posts and tags)

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable


  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :content, :tag_name

  attr_accessor :tag_name

  validates :title,   :presence => true,
                      :length   => { :maximum => 30 },
                      :uniqueness => true
  validates :content, :presence => true,
                      :uniqueness => true

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

  attr_writer :tag_names
  after_save :assign_tags

  def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
  end

  private

  def assign_tags
    if @tag_names
      self.tags = @tag_names.split(" ").map do |name|
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Right now, the currently logged user (via [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)) see all the posts:

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  autocomplete :tag, :name

  def index
    @title = "Posts"
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end
```

**views/posts/index.html.erb:**

```
<div id="mainbar" class="nine columns">

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
      <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>

      <div class="post_content">
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
      </div>

  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

I want to enable users to follow/subscribe tags so they only see posts with these tags in the index page.

How would be the Model and migration to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

Everything works fine now but I get this error when I enter the index page:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation):
    2:   <h2><%= @title %></h2>
    3: 
    4:   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    5:     <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
    6:       <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
    7: 
    8:       <div class="post-meta">
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:5:in `block in _app_views_posts_index_html_erb__75789648_88240890'
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:4:in `each'
  app/views/posts/index.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__75789648_88240890'
```

the index view for posts:

```
<div id="mainbar" class="nine columns">
  <h2><%= @title %></h2>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div id="post-<%= post.id %>" class="post">
      <h3><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>

      <div class="post-meta">
        <span><%= link_to post.user.username, post.user %></span>
        <span>Created At: <%= post.created_at %></span>
      </div>

      <div class="post-content">
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
      </div>

      <p>Votes: <%= post.total_votes %></p>
      <p>Comments: <%= post.comments_count %></p>
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to 'Show', post %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></li>
      </ul>
      <br />
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= will_paginate @posts %>
  <p><%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path, :class => 'sunset-orange button radius' %></p>
</div>

<div id="sidebar" class="three column">
  <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a user can subscribe to many tags and a tag can be subscribed by many users, you will need to associate User and Tag by `has_many` association ( either through `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through` similar to Tag and Post models' association).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_tags, :source => :tag, :through => :subscriptions

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribed_users, :source => :user, :through => :subscriptions

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag  
  belongs_to :user
```

Then in PostsController, select all posts with tags that the user has subscribed to.

```
def index
  @posts = current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:posts).flatten.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
end
```

If you are using Will Paginate for pagination, you might get an `undefined method 'paginate' for Arrays` error, since using `map` will result in an array. So, you might need to add `require 'will_paginate/array'` to the corresponding controller.

Comment: Thanks! Everything worked. I have a post with the tag food and did user = User.last...user.subscribed_tags.create(:name => "food"). The user subscribed to the tag but when I enter the index page I got the error in my **EDIT**.

Comment: Yea, add the require part to posts controller since `current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:posts)` will result in an array of post objects.

Comment: Sorry see my comment again I think you didn't see the update. I think something is wrong with the code in the index action because everythig works OK if I use the old one (I also added the whole index view).

Comment: First the answer - I suggest `array.flatten` before paginate, i.e. `@posts = current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:posts).flatten.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)`. Now the reason - `current_user.subscribed_tags` will yield in an array itself say [tagA, tagB]. Now if both these tags have 2 posts associated then `current_user.subscribed_tags.map(&:posts)` will yield [[postA1, postA2], [postB1, postB2]] , i.e. arrays within an array. So, in the first run in `@posts.each` block, post is actually [post1,post2] and not any post object. So, calling id results in an error.

Comment: So, calling `.flatten` on the array will make it [postA1, postA2, postB1, postB2]. Then you can loop over each post and call its methods on it. Cheers!